# How to make SBT not reporting compilation warnings for generated code?

Tags: scala, sbt

I generate code with the scalaxb-sbt plugin that, when compiled, generates a good number of warning messages. Is there any way to hide compilation warnings for generated code or by package?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## For Scala 2.12.13+ or  2.13.2+

Recent versions of the Scala compiler integrate the silencer plugin, see [configurable warnings](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html).
So now you don't need any plugin, just add the following line to `build.sbt`:

```scala
ThisBuild / scalacOptions += "-Wconf:src=src_managed/.*:silent"
```

Using this option will suppress warnings for generated code that lives under a directory called `src_managed` anywhere in your source tree.

This solved my problem with code generated by `zio-grpc`, where the compiler emitted warnings like `parameter value evidence$3 in method live is never used` (adding this info only for better searchability).

Answer (score 8):

The [silencer](https://github.com/ghik/silencer) compiler plugin allows to suppress compiler warnings. It supports filtering out files by path. This will filter out all generated files from warnings:

```scala
scalacOptions += "-P:silencer:pathFilters=src_managed"
```

Answer (score 3):

In your sbt console you could try the following:
`set logLevel in compile := Level.Error` or eventually `set logLevel in sourceGenerators := Level.Error`
and experiment with different settings. Once you are happy you could apply this setting in your `build.sbt`.

More detailed information can be found in the sbt documentation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Howto/logging.html

Comment: That turns all warnings off and, I'm asking for selectively do so.

Answer (score 2):

I found that I needed to do `set logLevel in Compile := Level.Error` in my sbt console session in order for this to work. This is with a capital `C` in `Compile`. This is with sbt version `0.13.11`. This is also to turn all warnings off, though.

Comment: I also needed to add my project like: `set logLevel in search in Compile := Level.Error`

Answer (score 1):

Put the code in a subproject, and set `scalacOptions` differently in that project? Whether this will work depends on whether the support even exists in scalac for suppressing the particular kind of warning you are getting.  See for example https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1781 . What kind of warnings are you needing to suppress exactly? Certain warnings like unchecked warnings can be suppressed with e.g. `@unchecked` without having to do the subproject thing.