# How to disable specific plugins for generated source code in sbt?

Tags: sbt

In one of my projects, I am using [sbt-tpolecat](https://github.com/DavidGregory084/sbt-tpolecat) plugin to ensure recommended scalac flags are enabled including extra linting. My normal source code in `src/main/scala` is passing all the checks. However, the source code generated by [scalaxb](https://scalaxb.org/) is not passing the checks. The source code is generated under `target/scala-2.13/src_managed/main`. Is there anyway to exclude or disable specific plugins for generated source code in sbt?

Comment: See my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66354074/1276804) for Scala 2.12.13+ or 2.13.2+.